# Knockout binding and jquery dialog window

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I'm trying to deal with knockout example that shows how to bind viewModel to jquery dialog window: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/WpnTU/
I'm trying to make this example work in MVC4 Internet application, all I do is copying code below to standart Index view. But when i click on buttons, dialog window doesn't open. Tell me please, what am i doing wrong?

```
 @section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        //custom binding to initialize a jQuery UI dialog
        $(document).ready(function () {
            ko.bindingHandlers.jqDialog = {
                init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                    var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};

                    //handle disposal
                    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                        $(element).dialog("destroy");
                    });

                    //dialog is moved to the bottom of the page by jQuery UI. Prevent initial pass of ko.applyBindings from hitting it
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(element).dialog(options);
                    }, 0);
                }
            };

            //custom binding handler that opens/closes the dialog
            ko.bindingHandlers.openDialog = {
                update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                    if (value) {
                        $(element).dialog("open");
                    } else {
                        $(element).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            }

            //custom binding to initialize a jQuery UI button
            ko.bindingHandlers.jqButton = {
                init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                    var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};

                    //handle disposal
                    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                        $(element).button("destroy");
                    });

                    $(element).button(options);
                }
            };

            var Product = function (id, name, isNew) {
                this.id = ko.observable(id);
                this.name = ko.observable(name);
                this.isNew = isNew;
                this.editId = ko.observable(id);
                this.editName = ko.observable(name);

                //persist edits to real values on accept
                this.accept = function () {
                    this.id(this.editId()).name(this.editName());
                }.bind(this);

                //reset to originals on cancel
                this.cancel = function () {
                    this.editId(this.id()).editName(this.name());
                }.bind(this);
            }

            var ViewModel = function () {
                var self = this;
                this.productList = ko.observableArray([
                    new Product(1, "one"),
                    new Product(2, "two"),
                    new Product(3, "three"),
                    new Product(4, "four")
                ]);

                this.selectedProduct = ko.observable();
                this.editProduct = function (productToEdit) {
                    self.selectedProduct(productToEdit);
                };
                this.addProduct = function () {
                    self.selectedProduct(new Product(0, "", true));
                },
                this.removeProduct = function (product) {
                    self.productList.remove(product);
                },
                this.accept = function () {
                    var selected = self.selectedProduct();
                    selected.accept();

                    if (selected.isNew) {
                        self.productList.push(new Product(selected.id(), selected.name()));
                    }

                    self.selectedProduct("");
                },
                this.cancel = function () {
                    self.selectedProduct().cancel();
                    self.selectedProduct("");
                };
            };

            ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
        })
    </script>
        }
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: productList">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td> 
            <td>
                <button data-bind="click: $root.editProduct">Edit</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button data-bind="click: $root.removeProduct">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>

<button data-bind="click: addProduct">Add Product</button>


<hr />

<div id="details" data-bind="jqDialog: { autoOpen: false, resizable: false, modal: true }, 
    template: { name: 'editTmpl', data: selectedProduct, if: selectedProduct }, openDialog: selectedProduct"> 
</div>

<script id="editTmpl" type="text/html">
    <p>
        <label>ID: </label>
        <input data-bind="value: editId"  />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input data-bind="value: editName"  />
    </p>        
    <button data-bind="jqButton: {}, click: $root.accept">Accept</button>
    <button data-bind="jqButton: {}, click: $root.cancel">Cancel</button>
</script>
```

Comment: Have checked your browser console? please list errors if present

Comment: Don't novice programmers understand that novice troubleshooting is a MAIN function in their job? How can you post up all of this code and not even discuss what it's doing wrong or your theories on why?

Comment: @bios "Uncaught referenceError: JQuery is not defined@ in jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js

Comment: @user2827899 : I think the problem is because of using jQuery latest version and jQueryUI old version try using latest jQueryUI.

Comment: @bios Thanks a lot, that's really was the reason of that error, now I'll try to resolve new one: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close' :)

Comment: all errors dissapeared after changing js files:

    <link href="~/Content/jquery.ui.dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Now everything works, no errors in Firebug.
But dialog window doesn't open, information from #details shows on same page below.
I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery and jQuery UI latest versions because its works for me, if any problem occures in your code then use **[jQuery Migrate](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/)** plugin and find out all errors and correct it. before going to use jQuery Migrate read something about it..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because of using jQuery latest version and jQueryUI old version try using latest **[jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/download/)**.